# Peformance Issue Sending Bulk Email Using Spring JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp

I have a cron job created under Spring Boot application which sends bulk reminder emails. Right now I am using [Spring JavaMailSender](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html) to send emails. Need to send 100k emails in the shortest period of time. Here is a simple process diagram to explain how the whole process is executing

[image: remidner-email-process]

There are 2 issues I am facing.

1. Sending a single email is taking 1200-1600 milliseconds. Here are SMTP configuration
   `port: 25 connectiontimeout: 5000 timeout: 5000 writetimeout: 5000 starttls.enable: true`. Does using port 25 with TLS enabled effects the performance of sending emails, or should I use port 587? How can I improve performance in this area
2. When the email sending process reaches 21-22k, I started getting `SocketTimeoutException` but with the next iteration of the cron job email was processed successfully with 5-6 emails getting SocketTimeoutException. Can this be related to some connection limit from SMTP server-side ([Message rate limits and throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/message-rate-limits?view=exchserver-2016))